# E: Sub-process returned an error code when running sudo apt-get update

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I wanted to install some updates of apps that I am using on my ubuntu, but couldn't and I tried to run sudo apt-get update and this is what I got

```
sudo apt-get update
Hit:1 http://ppa.launchpad.net/otto-kesselgulasch/gimp/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Hit:2 http://repository.spotify.com stable InRelease                           
Hit:3 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                   
Hit:4 http://ppa.launchpad.net/yannubuntu/boot-repair/ubuntu bionic InRelease  
Hit:5 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease              
Hit:6 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease                     
Hit:7 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease             
Hit:8 https://download.sublimetext.com apt/stable/ InRelease             
Hit:9 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease
sh: 1: /usr/lib/cnf-update-db: not found           
Reading package lists... Done
E: Problem executing scripts APT::Update::Post-Invoke-Success 'if /usr/bin/test -w /var/lib/command-not-found/ -a -e /usr/lib/cnf-update-db; then /usr/lib/cnf-update-db > /dev/null; fi'
E: Sub-process returned an error code
```

There is an error which I am not familiar with, can someone help?

Also I tried to install -f as I saw it as a solution, but it didn't work for me, this is what I got:

```
sudo apt-get install –f
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package –f
```

Thank you for the help!

Comment: Any chance it could be linked to https://medium.com/nttlabs/ubuntu-21-10-and-fedora-35-do-not-work-on-docker-20-10-9-1cd439d9921?